# Set user agent for IE9 (GWT)

Tags: java, gwt

I'm trying to change the user agent to safari when the page is visited using IE9.

I wrote this to the gwt.xml file:

```
<set-property name='user.agent' value='safari'>
   <when-property-is name="user.agent" value="ie9" />
</set-property>
```

However IE9 now doesn't find any user agent at all (doesn't even fall back to its own).
What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** I have to use GWT 2.0.4

**EDIT2:** Read comments of answer to see how I fixed it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't done it before, but I assume you will have to implement your own UserAgentPropertyGenerator (because this is the class that evaluates the user agent property dynamically!), and then bind it like in com.google.gwt.user.UserAgent.gwt.xml:

```
<property-provider 
   name="user.agent"
   generator="com.google.gwt.user.rebind.UserAgentPropertyGenerator"/>
```

For older versions of GWT (< 2.3.0), this is configured directly in com.google.gwt.user.UserAgent.gwt.xml as:

```
  <property-provider name="user.agent"><![CDATA[
      var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
      var makeVersion = function(result) {
        return (parseInt(result[1]) * 1000) + parseInt(result[2]);
      };

      if (ua.indexOf("opera") != -1) {
        return "opera";
      } else if (ua.indexOf("webkit") != -1) {
        return "safari";
      } else if (ua.indexOf("msie") != -1) {
        if (document.documentMode >= 8) {
          return "ie8";
        } else {
          var result = /msie ([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)/.exec(ua);
          if (result && result.length == 3) {
            var v = makeVersion(result);
            if (v >= 6000) {
              return "ie6";
            }
          }
        }
      } else if (ua.indexOf("gecko") != -1) {
        var result = /rv:([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)/.exec(ua);
        if (result && result.length == 3) {
          if (makeVersion(result) >= 1008)
            return "gecko1_8";
          }
        return "gecko";
      }
      return "unknown";
  ]]></property-provider>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be possible in GWT 2.0.4 is it?

Comment: @Rob: Yes, this is new in GWT 2.3.0. I updated my answer to also cover older versions of GWT.

Comment: Thanks! However I get an error running this on any version of IE: Error while executing the JavaScript provider for property 'user.agent'
com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError): 'odoc' is undefined

Comment: The problem was actually in how I checked for IE9 (odoc.body.style.opacity != undefined) that caused lower IEs to throw errors. I changed it to if (document.documentMode >= 9) return 'safari' and it worked!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% sure that I understand your question. However, I believe you can't really *change* the user agent. What you probably want to do is handling requests from ie9 browser as if they were coming from safari browsers. In this case I think you can use [Deferred Binding Using Replacement](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDeferred.html#replacement): the example in this web page would look something like this for you:

```
<module>

  <!--  ... other configuration omitted ... -->

  <!-- Fall through to this rule is the browser isn't IE or Mozilla -->
  <replace-with class="com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.impl.PopupImpl">
    <when-type-is class="com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.impl.PopupImpl"/>
  </replace-with>

  <!-- Handling safari and ie9 in the same way -->
  <replace-with class="com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.impl.PopupImplSafari">
    <when-type-is class="com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.impl.PopupImpl" />
    <any>
      <when-property-is name="user.agent" value="safari"/>
      <when-property-is name="user.agent" value="ie9" />
    </any>
  </replace-with>

</module>
```

Comment: Using <set-property name='user.agent' value='safari'> works. It's the <when..> term that doesn't work. Based on given code I can't understand how to write anything better than I already did.